# Undefined property $request | LiipImagineBundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundles

Исходные данные по вопросу:

1. Фреймворк Symfony2
2. Bundle LiipImagineBundle для нарезки миниатюр изображений.

Задача: генерировать миниатюры в контроллере. 
В документации нашел вот такой фрагмент кода:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
{
    // RedirectResponse object
    $imagemanagerResponse = $this->container
        ->get('liip_imagine.controller')
        ->filterAction(
            $this->request,         // http request
            'uploads/foo.jpg',      // original image you want to apply a filter to
            'my_thumb'              // filter defined in config.yml
        );

    // string to put directly in the "src" of the tag <img>
    $cacheManager = $this->container->get('liip_imagine.cache.manager');
    $srcPath = $cacheManager->getBrowserPath('uploads/foo.jpg', 'my_thumb');

    // ..
    }
}
```

Однако при вставке в контроллер я получаю ошибку "Notice: Undefined property: AppBundle\Controller\MyController::$request".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно передать $request в метод контроллера:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
    // RedirectResponse object
    $imagemanagerResponse = $this->container
        ->get('liip_imagine.controller')
        ->filterAction(
            $request,         // http request
            'uploads/foo.jpg',      // original image you want to apply a filter to
            'my_thumb'              // filter defined in config.yml
        );

    // string to put directly in the "src" of the tag <img>
    $cacheManager = $this->container->get('liip_imagine.cache.manager');
    $srcPath = $cacheManager->getBrowserPath('uploads/foo.jpg', 'my_thumb');

    // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!